# charging Laptop Batteries

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good practices for making sure my laptop battery serves it's full life?](https://superuser.com/questions/197864/what-are-some-good-practices-for-making-sure-my-laptop-battery-serves-its-full-l)

How I should charge my laptop battery to have a long time life?

Comment: According to the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: i dont think you say true

Comment: all batteres have a best way to charge.. and company is Irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link over at [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) explains the basics for lithium ion batteries, the most common type of rechargable batteries found in consumer electronics. Basically don't freeze or overheat the battery and don't frequently recharge and discharge the battery in short cycles.