# How to maximize notebook battery longevity?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, power-management, battery, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good practices for making sure my laptop battery serves its full life?](https://superuser.com/questions/197864/what-are-some-good-practices-for-making-sure-my-laptop-battery-serves-its-full-li)

The battery on my **ThinkPad T410** only lasted for one year.  Now, when "fully charged", it will only power the computer for less than 20 minutes.

The battery is the Lenovo 55++, which is a 94 Wh, 9-cell **Lithium-ion battery**.  I use the computer every day, almost always connected to AC power.  When I am not using the computer (for instance while traveling from home to work), it is in standby mode.

I run **Ubuntu linux** 10.04.2.

This seems like a very short lifetime for a battery (**1 year**), which leads me to ask:

1. **Is this normal?**
2. **Is the battery broken?**
3. Or **am I doing it wrong?** i.e. is there something I should be doing to prolong the battery life?  Is keeping the computer plugged into AC power when available not a good thing to do? Is there a problem with Linux's power management? etc.

*What is the best way to maximize total battery longevity?*

Answer (score 2):

I have a 2 year old Lenovo T61 that has absolutely no battery capacity left in it. I had my battery replaced about a year ago as it was under a recall, although I'm having the exact issue one year later.

First, I would check out the following link to see if battery was recalled:
http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=BATT-LENOVO

I think the problem I was having is that I was leaving it plugged in quite literally 24/7 and it was killing my lithium-ion battery. Knowing what I know now, I would remove the battery when it is plugged in for extended periods of time and/or use the battery life and charge only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give a comprehensive answer, but one thing is: do not use standby when unplugged! Standby does drain the battery (although more slowly than when the system is actually active), and Li-Ion cells have a limited number of charge cycles.

If you don't want to shut down, use hibernate instead. A properly hibernated computer will use as little current as one that is turned off.

Note: a BIOS bug on some HP laptops causes them to discharge the battery even when hibernated. This was fixed for my own laptop in a BIOS upgrade in 2007, IIRC. There may be a similar problem with your ThinkPad. Check Lenovo's site for BIOS upgrades.

For long periods of disuse, remove the battery completely.