# How to take best care of my battery

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good practices for making sure my laptop battery serves its full life?](https://superuser.com/questions/197864/what-are-some-good-practices-for-making-sure-my-laptop-battery-serves-its-full-l)

I bought a new battery for my Lenovo the other day, and want to take better care of it than the last one.

So, what is the best practices for taking care of it?

Should I only fully charge and fully drain the battery every time?

If I won't use the battery for a while, should I keep it fully charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I won't use the battery for a while, should I keep it fully charged?

Store it at 40% charge, cycle it on a monthly basis

> So, what is the best practices for taking care of it?

When you are using it, if backup time is not critical, set it to start charging at 40% and stop at 80%

> Should I only fully charge and fully drain the battery every time?

NO, thats a recipe for killing the battery

Sample settings from my Lenovo [image]

Comment: Thanks. How can set it to start charging at 40% and stop at 80%?

Comment: @Anders Updated answer with screenshot. Go to Power manager->Battery->Battery maintenance

Comment: I have to install that Lenovo software, just reinstalled Windows and don't use all of the Lenovo software. Is it possible to do it without the tool?

Comment: @Anders go to http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE And Download the application. Use it to install all the utilities you want

Comment: I dont know of a way to do it without the utility

Comment: I use a docking station at home. Is it possible to make it not use the battery while at the docking station?

Comment: @Anders I have never used a docking station, but I dont see why the laptop would treat the docking station as being different from AC power: use the battery if AC power dies, charge the battery if charge conditions are met else dont do anything to the battery