# new laptop battery usage

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a new hp laptop 4cell battery I am confused about using battery and charging it I have read it is not suitable to keep it pluged in all the time but where I live it has power fluctuation sometimes and it is not convenient to take in and out the battery every time so please suggest a good way to use laptop battery and to prolong its life is it better to be plugged in even after reaching 100% charge or is it better to charge it to say 85% then discharge it till 30% then again charge it??

Comment: Leaving your battery in your laptop DOES decrease battery life. (Personal experience, with already like a dozen of laptops.) || Solution: Get a battery off ebay for cheap, and use that one for this power surge purpose. And keep your original battery in a dry / good place for batteries, so when you need battery life,  you just pop that in.

Comment: Charge it at about 40% and stop it at going above 90%. If you can, do take the battery out when using near a plug source do so, may be invest in a UPS if you have power issues where you are. Although that may be more expensive. If you can replace the battery though, then just buy a spare battery!

Comment: Root through the manufacturer-specific power controls and look for something like "Battery Care".  DO NOT purposely "cycle" the battery, as that shortens battery life vs maintaining a steady 85% or so charge.

Comment: If you are worried about the battery ( not sure the reason ) just remove it.

Comment: Please don't repeat your existing questions. There are lots of resources available on this topic, so please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/449157/increasing-laptop-battery-service-life). Recommended is the following: When you don't need the battery, charge it to 40-60%, remove it and store it in a cool place (ideal is 10 to 20°C). Make sure to do some 20-80% cycles every quarter, though. It's generally a good idea to use the wall plug with removed battery when you run CPU/GPU-heavy applications like games with 3D graphics. Fluctuating voltage shouldn't be too big of a problem, as your charger will mitigate that.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore posts about charging the battery to a certain percentage, and draining... this was true many years ago for old style batteries. Not important anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your battery backup! when playing on battery,ensure that your power configuration is on balanced or high performance so that your 'heavy' game can use all resources(processor) because in power saving mode,its block to using all resources to use to save power!
If you are worry about your battery,so you need to know that if your battery is 100% charge and your lappy is plugged in,then it uses power directly not from battery!so don't worry about it!
Use full charge and full discharge method to increase battery life!

So in short play games with plugged in until you want to play outside of the home or power cuttage !
(Use some game boosters too :) )
If you need some more help then commnet! :)

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with both Shiki and Dave Rook. This information is so yesterday. All modern laptops have smart battery management systems. These systems will perform partial charge/discharge cycles without user even noticing it. Also the battery technology has improved through last years and modern batteries are much more reliable.

Saying that leaving the battery in your laptop DOES decrease battery life is equivalent to saying that using the battery does decrease the battery life. And what else did you expect? An alternative to *using the batter* is *not using the battery* which adds up to running off the AC. And OP has clearly mentioned power fluctuations. So you are suggesting the guy with no stable AC supply to remove his battery?

With modern laptop and a decent battery, even if you keep it in the machine at all times and you have AC adapter online 90% of the time, your laptop will become old and outdated or it will malfunction long time before your battery deteriorates to unusable state. Also, if by some chance your battery does deteriorate, buying a new one is much cheaper then getting yourself a UPS and much much cheaper then suffering losses that you might get if your laptop powers off and loses data.

So the answer is, if you have power fluctuations in your area, DO NOT remove the battery ever, as you will be in the risk of shutting off power to the running machine and losing valuable data.

Also, since modern laptops perform clever battery management routines, you manually messing around with the charging/discharging will only make it worse. The technology is there to make your life easier. Just sit back and enjoy.

You can also read [this short article](http://blogs.which.co.uk/technology/laptops-2/top-5-laptop-battery-myths-which-did-you-believe/). There is plenty of the information on the web about how to properly take care of your batteries, but remember that a lot them will be outdated, as the technology is developing quickly.

Comment: +/-1 Many laptops have "smart battery management", but it often must be enabled.  My Sony has a "Battery Care" function which must be enabled.  It limits charging to about 85%.  From the factory the unit will charge to 100% and battery life will be significantly impacted.

Answer (score -1):

Most laptop batteries these days are Lithium Ion based - so constant charging won't hurt them. This seems logical as most people don't even realise that batery care is even "a thing" let alone important.

Good tips for looking after a battery include:

- Avoid frequent complete discharge of a batter as contraty to popular
  belief, this can actually put strain on a lithium battery.
- Keep the battery and laptop cool. No notter than 95degrees for an
  extended period of time.
- Consider removing the battery if you are planning to work the laptop
  hard on mains for an extended period of time
- Calibrate your battery and guage by doing occasional (not frequent)
  full discharge/charge cycles
- Lithium batteries degrade over time - when buying a new battery for
  your laptop, buy a "new" battery - not one from old stock
- When storing the laptop unused for a long period of time, store it
  with some charge, but not full charge and do a calibration charge
  when you put it back into service.
- Storing at 100% or empty is bad for the battery. try storing at half
  charge or just below
- Look into buying high capacity batteries rather than spares - this
  can often server better.

Most important out of the above is to remember that heat destroys batteries a lot faster than a bad charge/discharge pattern. Lithium batteries are "memory free" which means that charging from part-charged or not doesn't make much of an impact (if any) and most damage done over a long, bad charge/discharge life can be undone with a calibration or two.

[This document](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-extending-lithium-ion-battery-life/) (although not the source for my info) contains mostly the same information and probably explains better than I could

Comment: Too much bad advice there to even list.